# Running CMD line in C++ Using variables (not string literals) as Params

Tags: c++, cmd

I've executed this command in the CMD window and it works.  I now need to run it in 2015 VC++ program code but I cannot get it. 
I've read the various posts dealing with this but they are mainly for string literals and I have variables.   I think this is throwing off the double quotes.  I do not have to use _wsystem if there is a better/safer way.

UPDATED:

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss <<  std::wstring(L"\"") << CPathUtil::get_exe_fullpath() << std::wstring(L"\"") << L" /q /a " << std::wstring(L"\"") + cp.c_str() + std::wstring(L"\"");
const auto command = wss.str();
const auto result = _wsystem(command.c_str());
```

It still does not run from VC++ app..
`command = "C:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svn_3dg_wc\x64\Debug\MyAppD.exe" /q /a "C:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svn_3dg_wc\Samples\New folder\C - Copy (2).abc"`
If I copy value from debugger and paste into CMD window, it works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes you add in the last step before calling `_wsystem` turn the whole string into a *single command*. The quotes are needed to group space-delimited "words" in the command.

The contents of `param` should be something like

```
"C:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svn_wc\x64\Debug\MyApp.exe" /q /a "C:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svn_3dg_wc\Samples\New folder\C - Copy (2).abc"
```

Note that the `/q /a` part is *not* within quotes, only the paths to the files (which contains spaces and therefore needs the quotes).

Also note that there's no multiple of quotes anywhere, only single double-quotes.